# [Thread sync]Make a print thread wait for n threads to finish a single cycle of execution, then signal the n threads to complete another cycle, repeat

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

How can I have a single thread wait for n threads to complete a single execution cycle, then repeat this for i cycles. The solution needs to use semaphores to signal the single thread that all n threads have completed an execution cycle. The single thread should then signal ALL n threads that they can carry on with one more execution, ...repeat.

Some challenges I can't fix:

- Controlling the semaphores so that one of the n threads doesn't eat up more than one cycle (semaphore post/wait).
- The n number of workers is only known at run time, so we can't initialize a sem_t array[n].

:

```
//these would have been read in at run time
int n = 4;
int control = 4;

void *worker(void* args){
    int num = (int)args;
    printf("Worker id: %d\n", num);
    int proceed = 5; // simulates "5" jobs in this workers queue
    while(proceed > 0){
        sem_wait(&execute);
        printf("Report from: %d\n", num);
        sem_post(&reports);
        proceed--;
    }
    control--;
} 

void *print(){
    while(control > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sem_wait(&reports);
        }
        printf("All reported\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sem_post(&execute);
        }
    }
}

void main(){
    // control/n would have been scanned and passed to threads, the global control var 
    would be set after reading in n
    sem_init(&execute,0,n);    //initialization of the first semaphore
    sem_init(&reports,0,0);    //initialization of the second semaphore

    pthread_t printer;
    pthread_create(&printer,NULL, &print,NULL);

    pthread_t workers[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int* num = malloc(sizeof(int));
        num = i;
        pthread_create(&(workers[i]),NULL, &worker, (void*)num);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pthread_join(workers[i],NULL);
    }

    pthread_join(printer,NULL);
}
```

Output:

```
[rnitz]$ gcc -Wall -Werror -w -g example2.c -std=gnu99 -lpthread 
[rnitz]$ ./a.out
Worker id: 0
Worker id: 3
Report from: 3
Report from: 3
Worker id: 2
Worker id: 1
Report from: 3
Report from: 0
All reported
Report from: 1
Report from: 0
Report from: 2
Report from: 3
All reported
Report from: 0
Report from: 1
Report from: 3
Report from: 2
All reported
Report from: 0
Report from: 0
Report from: 1
Report from: 2
All reported
Report from: 2
Report from: 1
Report from: 1
Report from: 2
All reported
[rnitz]$
```

Pretty obvious issue where some workers are eating up all the available "cycle" room in the semaphore.

Note: This question is based on simulating a cpu, where n is the number of cpu threads that will work on an their own independent job queue; while a single print thread handles printing the current job being processed for a given cpu cycle. The print thread will:

1. Wait for all cpus to finish a cycle
2. Print the current job on each cpu
3. Signal the n cpus to complete another cycle.

Comment: I'll publish an answer, but you have a race condition with the `condition--` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: `sem_t*` array of semaphores that are malloc'd at run time.. I couldn't find an example of this anywhere but ended up trying, and having it work :)

I'm keeping the question because I can't find anything similar on SOF, understandably waiting for n threads to synch on every cycle probably isn't common

For this, you can use arrays of semaphores instead of incrementing/decrementing a single semaphore. At minimum you will need at least one semaphore array, this solution uses 2.

This solution can be extended if the worker threads each have a different amount of jobs to complete, you can have a global int that decrements when a thread is finished, which would be then be used in the for-loops of the printer thread. That way if 1  of the n threads is done early due to less work, you can sem_wait()/sem_post n-1 times.

```
sem_t* execute_arr;
sem_t* reports_arr;

//this both need to be the same value
int n = 4;
int control = 4;

void *worker(void* args){
    int num = (int)args;
    //printf("init arg: %d\n", num);
    int proceed = 5;
    while(proceed > 0){
        sem_wait(&execute_arr[num]);
        printf("Report from: %d\n", num);
        sem_post(&reports_arr[num]);
        proceed--;
    }
    control--;
    //free memory and/or destroy sems if needed
} 

void *print(){
    while(control > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sem_wait(&reports_arr[i]);
        }
        printf("All reported\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sem_post(&execute_arr[i]);
        }
    }
}

void main(){
    execute_arr = (sem_t*)malloc(n * sizeof(sem_t));
    reports_arr = (sem_t*)malloc(n * sizeof(sem_t));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sem_init(&execute_arr[i], 0, 1);
        sem_init(&reports_arr[i], 0, 0);
    }

    pthread_t printer;
    pthread_create(&printer,NULL, &print,NULL);

    pthread_t workers[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int* num = malloc(sizeof(int));
        num = i;
        pthread_create(&(workers[i]),NULL, &worker, (void*)num);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pthread_join(workers[i],NULL);
    }

    pthread_join(printer,NULL);
    //free memory and/or destroy sems if needed
}
```

And the fixed output:

```
[rnitz]$ ./a.out
Report from: 1
Report from: 0
Report from: 2
Report from: 3
All reported
Report from: 1
Report from: 3
Report from: 0
Report from: 2
All reported
Report from: 1
Report from: 3
Report from: 2
Report from: 0
All reported
Report from: 1
Report from: 3
Report from: 2
Report from: 0
All reported
Report from: 1
Report from: 3
Report from: 0
Report from: 2
All reported
[rnitz]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a system semaphore, a mutex and a couple of condition variables would work well here for this type of problem.

I'll leave the unfinished work of `main` to initialize the global mutex and condition variables in the code sample as an exercise for you.

```
pthread_mutex mutex;
pthread_cond_t cv_thread;
pthread_cond_t cv_main;

int job_number = 0;
int completions = 0;
int exit_condition = 0;
int n = 4; //number of worker threads

void *worker(void* args){
    int num = (int)args;
    int lastJobNumber = 0;
    int must_exit = 0;

    while (1) {    

        // wait for the main thread to indicate a new job is ready
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

            while ((lastJobNumber >= job_number) && !exit_condition) {
              pthread_cond_wait(&cv_thread, &mut);  // wait for job_number to change or for exit_conditon to be set
            }

            must_exit = exit_condition;

            if (!must_exit) {
                lastJobNumber = job_number;  // take on the new job!
            }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        if (must_exit) {
            break;
        }

        printf("Report from: %d.  This thread is executing job %d\n", num, lastJobNumber);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            completions++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv_main); // signal to main to wake up
    }
} 


void *print() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            job_number++;
            completions = 0;

            // signal to threads a new job is ready
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv_thread);

            // wait for all threads to indicate completion
            while (completions < n) {
                pthread_cond_wait(&cv_main, &mutex); 
            }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        printf("All reported\n");
   }

    // signal all threads to exit
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        exit_condition = 1;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv_thread);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```